# deep-extend 0.5.1 has known vulnerabilities

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, electron-builder

Could you please help me this problem.

When I audit by **npm audit**. It noticed that ***deep-extend 0.5.1 has known vulnerabilities***

In package-lock.json, I can find the root of issue

```
  electron-builder > package-json > registry-url > rc > deep-extend
```

I use newest version of **electron-builder** in devDependencies

```
"devDependencies": {
    "electron": "2.0.2",
    "electron-builder": "20.14.7",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "2.2.4",
    "foreman": "3.0.0"
  }
```

Can anybody help me to ignore the above audit? Thank you very much

Comment: So, what is your actual question? How to fix the known vulnerabilities in deep-extend ..?

Comment: Yes sir, I'm so sorry for the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If electron-builder depend on **latest** deep-extend and latest deep-extend has vulnerabilities and you care, you are in trouble and have 3 options.

- Report this problem to the maintainers and hope this will be fixed until your release.
- Fix this by your own, make a pull request to the deep-extend and hope they will accept it until your release.
- Fork deep-extend, electron-builder, patch both of them, publish on npm. Than switch when they will fix the problem. This is the hardest way.

If electron-builder depend **not on latest** deep-extend, you can add propper deep-extend version to your package.json and electron will try to use it.

Not sure this helps you much still.

Comment: thank you very much. I solved problem. I use 'resolution' property of yarn. And it worked

Comment: @nguyennani great to hear that this helps